# XPS 13 9350 (2016) suspend - sound issues

Tags: sound, suspend, dell, xps

I own a Dell xps 13 9350 (2016) and from the beginning I had issues with suspend mode. When I would wake the machine up it would freeze and I have to reboot. I did a few system updates but then it thought some unknown audio-device was plugged in after waking it up and now, after rebooting from that, my whole soundcard is no longer detected...

Anyone else experiencing the same, or knows how I can get my soundcard back to be recognized and work?

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using a DELL XPS 13 9360 (late 2016) and experienced the same issues on suspend. the system would suspend but would not resume.

I have Ubuntu 16.10 installed with kernel version : 4.8.0-27-generic

What solved the issue for me is the installing of user-space uswsusp package.

```
sudo apt-get install uswsusp
```

Reference: [PowerManagement Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate)

Comment: Please watch out with this command. As I had a hanging ubuntu boot sequence on local-premount. I had a lot of problems undoing this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have the same problem. It was reported on the Dell Community Forums here: http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/f/4613/t/19682246

There seems to be no fix yet, but Dell has "replicated the issue in house", so I expect it won't take too long now.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here,

I got my xps 13 9350 last week. After I upgraded to xenial, I supended and resumed and lost all sound capabilities. It couldn't detect internal audio, the bluetooth device nor the dock station WD15. Reinstalling the whole system to Xenial fixed all my issues.