# Suspend broken on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Dell XPS 9350

Tags: kernel, 16.04, suspend, xps

Since I upgraded from Ubuntu 15.10 to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Dell XPS 9350, suspend is broken. When closing my lid the laptop will suspend, but resuming fails and it reboots. I tried `pm-suspend` and tried resuming, resuming failed and the laptop rebooted. I got the following errors when I got back into Ubuntu. The odd thing in my opinion is that it claims the kernel is not an official ubuntu package. Either way my Linux knowledge is not sufficient to know what's going wrong here.

[image: Suspend/resume failure part 1]

[image: Suspend/resume failure part 2]

EDIT: I just tried installing kernel 4.4.8 which should fix some things, but it did not fix this problem. By now I also tried 4.4.9 and 4.6 RC7. None of them fixed it for me.

Comment: FWIW, I'm seeing this on what was a clean 16.04 install 2-3 weeks ago as well, so not sure it's related to the 15.10 -> 16.04 upgrade.

Comment: Another thing that might be worth noting is that I didn't see this behavior before yesterday or maybe a couple of days ago, after not having used the computer for a few days. Suspending used to work just fine in the beginning.

Comment: Hi Rien, smells like a UEFI/ACPI setting problem. I would recommend you start reading from here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/770629/in-ubuntu-16-04-which-acpi-global-state-does-suspend-result-in/775525

Comment: I found myself being able to suspend/resume again after some 'Important OS Updates'. These included updates for Python which I believe solved the problem. So anyone else having this problem might want to look into that, though I'm not sure that's what solved it

Comment: relevant bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1559469

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem on an XPS 15 9550. The only thing that worked for me was going into the bios and turning on "Block Sleep" under power options. This apparently turns off Intel Rapid Start and sleep (state 3). So technically the machine doesn't hibernate / suspend (state 3), but it does go to a higher sleep state when closing the lid / opening / power button and comes back fine. Seems like until the issue is addressed in the kernel, or driver this may be the only option and is the only thing that worked in my case.

**EDIT**: This script worked for me and I was able to turn off Block Sleep in bios! Sleep / suspend now works on my ubuntu 16.04:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2317843&page=11

Answer (score 1):

Resuming broke on my Dell XPS 13 9350 after I upgraded from 16.04 LTS to 17.10. When I would close the lid, as far as I could tell, the system suspended (though I'm guessing it probably crashed at that point). I see entries like this in /var/log/syslog:

```
Nov 22 21:42:01 foxy systemd[1]: Starting TLP suspend/resume...
Nov 22 21:42:02 foxy systemd[1]: Started TLP suspend/resume.
Nov 22 21:42:02 foxy systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Nov 22 21:42:02 foxy systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Nov 22 21:42:02 foxy systemd-sleep[3511]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Nov 22 21:42:02 foxy systemd-sleep[3519]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Nov 22 21:42:02 foxy systemd-sleep[3511]: Suspending system...
```

Those messages themselves don't really indicate anything unusual (at least for my system -- I'm curious what the errors mean). When I'd open the lid, I'd see a BIOS POST and the system would boot. This is reflected in the log, which had messages like these immediately following the chunk above:

```
Nov 22 21:49:24 foxy rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="891" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Nov 22 21:49:24 foxy rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 104
Nov 22 21:49:24 foxy rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
Nov 22 21:49:24 foxy rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole':: No such file or directory [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
Nov 22 21:49:24 foxy rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 11' suspended, next retry is Wed Nov 22 21:49:54 2017 [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Nov 22 21:49:24 foxy kernel: [    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x42/0x4e1 with crng_init=0
Nov 22 21:49:24 foxy kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.13.0-17-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-011) (gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3)) #20-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 6 10:04:08 UTC 2017 (Ubuntu 4.13.0-17.20-generic 4.13.8)
Nov 22 21:49:24 foxy kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-17-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=e51bd6de-6176-4dcf-aaa5-7030d32d15bb ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Nov 22 21:49:24 foxy kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Nov 22 21:49:24 foxy kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Nov 22 21:49:24 foxy kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Nov 22 21:49:24 foxy kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
...
```

Resume started working correctly after I installed the "uswsusp" package:

```
sudo apt-get install uswsusp
```

This is a solution described here: [XPS 13 9350 (2016) suspend - sound issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759994/xps-13-9350-2016-suspend-sound-issues)

Now, when I suspend, I see many more syslog entries indicating the system is properly going into suspend state:

```
Nov 22 22:49:41 foxy systemd[1]: Starting TLP suspend/resume...
Nov 22 22:49:42 foxy systemd[1]: Started TLP suspend/resume.
Nov 22 22:49:42 foxy systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Nov 22 22:49:42 foxy systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Nov 22 22:49:42 foxy systemd-sleep[3234]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Nov 22 22:49:42 foxy systemd-sleep[3241]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Nov 22 22:49:42 foxy systemd-sleep[3234]: Suspending system...
Nov 22 22:49:42 foxy kernel: [   51.749528] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Nov 22 22:49:42 foxy kernel: [   51.786975] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   51.788351] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.128 seconds) done.
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   51.917175] OOM killer disabled.
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   51.917176] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   51.918926] PM: Suspending system (mem)
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   51.919012] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   52.123320] psmouse serio1: Failed to disable mouse on isa0060/serio1
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.212355] PM: suspend of devices complete after 2293.959 msecs
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.234367] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 22.020 msecs
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.274131] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 39.764 msecs
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.274510] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.314470] ACPI: EC: event blocked
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.314471] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.314472] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.314586] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.330929] IRQ 283: no longer affine to CPU1
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.331951] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.352796] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.374594] IRQ 1: no longer affine to CPU3
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.374602] IRQ 8: no longer affine to CPU3
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.374606] IRQ 9: no longer affine to CPU3
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.374611] IRQ 12: no longer affine to CPU3
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.374615] IRQ 14: no longer affine to CPU3
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.374621] IRQ 16: no longer affine to CPU3
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.374626] IRQ 17: no longer affine to CPU3
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.374633] IRQ 51: no longer affine to CPU3
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.374641] IRQ 122: no longer affine to CPU3
Nov 22 22:49:59 foxy kernel: [   54.375694] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
```

Anyway, I don't know why the "uswsusp" package was missing or entirely why it fixed the problem. Seems like it should be a required package.

Comment: This area is over my head too. But as far as I understand it, [uswsusp](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate) replaces the `kernel/suspend`-hibernation. Still a riddle to me why suddenly I had suspend issues after 1-2 years of no issues.

Comment: Argh. I believe this had been working, but now I'm unable to suspend my laptop when it's running on battery. It apparently turns off when I close the lid, and it starts booting up from BIOS when I open the lid again. Suspend functions correctly when it's on A/C power.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a complete new re-install. When you have an usb-stick with 16.04 live Ubuntu, you only need to boot this usb-stick and install new only into the root-partition (/ - partition) of Ubuntu, while /home should not be overwritten. And the swap - partition will be overwritten too, this cannot harm and your working-space remains the same. After this successful installation you have a clean new 16.04 - Ubuntu (or xubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough swap space configured to do suspend and resume ?

Its tempting when you have oodles of RAM not to bother with swap space but if you don't have as much swap as RAM there is nowhere to resume from.

Run this command to see how much swap you have.

```
swapon
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my XPS 9550(16.04.2) I started tweaking different things on OS and GRUB level right away since I found a lot of threads similar to this one, but in the end what I discovered is that the latest BIOS update(1.2.25 from 05/07/2017) dropped some of the boot settings, more specifically "Enable UEFI network stack" and Secure Boot. You can find relevant instruction on [dell support site](http://www.dell.com/support/article/ua/ru/uabsdt1/SLN297060/xps-13-9343--how-to-install-ubuntu-developer-edition-1404-on-a-dell-pc-configured-for-the-unified-extensible-firmware-interface--uefi--bios?lang=EN).
To check your BIOS version:

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date
```

Answer (score -2):

try to make a complete install of the 16.04. from a bootable USB Stick. Make sure you have a internet connection and aktivat the update function befor you start the setup.
I´am not a linux pro, but over the years i learnt that it´s better to install ubuntu complete from a medium like USB-stick, CD, DVD...
I´am use a xps 13 9350 and it works with 16.04. for me perfect. (with kernel 4.4.2)

You can try to make a backup with deja-dup on 15.10 and recover it on 16.04 after you are sure it runs.

Sorry i can´t fix the problem, good luck.